# Date validation using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation

I'm working on a C#.NET web site and I've just started using entity framework and have created a model from an existing database.

I've added some validation using data annotations and this works well, but I'm not sure how to handle bad dates.

If I select an existing record from the database and then try and set one of its datetime properties to an invalid date then naturally I get an error at the point I try to set it.  What I would like to do is defer that error until I call GetValidationErrors() which I handle before the changes are saved.

```
var dbContext = new PlanEntities();
var plan = (from p in dbContext.Plan where p.PlanID == 123 select p).SingleOrDefault();

plan.StartDate = DateTime.Parse(StartDateInput.Value);  // Error here when bad date is given

ErrorMessage.InsertErrors(dbContext.GetValidationErrors());
```

The last line passes any validation errors to a user control.

I need to call DateTime.Parse as otherwise it won't compile so I'm guessing I need to change the model to accept strings instead of dates, but that doesn't seem right.  What I'd like to do is keep all validation in the model.

Comment: Why not use client side validation, and `DateTime` objects for the models instead of `String`

Comment: What is the value of StartDateInput.Value?

Comment: @3dd and when the client passes an invalid date (maybe the user blocks JS)? Still has to be validated in the server.

Comment: @Richard agreed but there is no need for using strings for dates and then parsing them, OP can just use `DataAnnotations` for the dates with `ModelBinding`

Comment: @3dd Assuming the he is using an up do date approach to ASP.NET, but the client may not be ASP.NET (as there is no such information in the Q).

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the error in your code.

Eg.

```
DateTime reqDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(inputString, out reqDate)) {
  // Any other, eg. range, checks...
  plan.StartDate = reqDate;
} else {
  // Report error back to the client.
}
```

even better would be `DateTime.TryParseExact` supplying an array of valid formats (and thus deal with US vs. everyone else ambiguities in dates like "03/05/2015").

How the error reporting is done depends on which framework you are using (WebForms vs. MVC). In MVC the date parsing can be handled by model binding.